# $A$ is similar in $\mathcal{M}_2 (\mathbb{C})$ to the matrix \begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 1\\0& \lambda\end{bmatrix}

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in \mathcal{M}_2 (\mathbb{C})$. If $Sp(A) = \{\lambda\}$ and $A$ is not a scalar matrix, show that $A$ is similar in $\mathcal{M}_2 (\mathbb{C})$ to the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 1\\0& \lambda\end{bmatrix}
$$
**My effort**

We have $\dim (E_\lambda)= 1$ then $E_\lambda = \text{spam}(u)$ $(Au=\lambda u)$. my problem is to find a non-zero vector $v$ satisfying $(A-\lambda I_2)v = u$ such that $\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Maybe look at $\ker (A-\lambda I)^2$?

Comment: $\ker (A-\lambda I)^2=\mathcal{M}_{21}(\mathbb{C})$. But how can that help me?

Comment: Pick some $v \in \ker (A-\lambda I)^2$ that is not in $\ker (A-\lambda I)$ and let $v= \ker (A-\lambda I)u$ for some $u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ must be $2$, you only have two possiblities: either the geometric multiplicity is $2$ (in which case the matrix would be a scalar matrix), or $1$. So the algebraic multiplicity is $1$. Because $(A-\lambda I)^2$ is the trivial linear transformation by Cayley-Hamilton, but $A-\lambda I$ is not, there is a vector $\mathbf{v}$ with the property that $(A-\lambda I)\mathbf{v}$ is nonzero, but lies in the nullspace of $A-\lambda I$.

Prove that $(A-\lambda I)\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are linearly independent.